# Excel pivot table relative information

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Is there anyway to show information without calculating anything in a pivot table in excel?

For example, I've got a pivot table with a number of invoices and it shows which products are billed in the invoices. I only want it to show the invoice date to the right of the invoice number, without summing it nor counting it or anything, I only want the information to be shown. The invoice date is in another column in the base sheet, by the way.

Thanks!

Comment: add is a row header... it will only sum/count if you place it the values section. So, in the Row Grouping, first field is `invoice number`, then `invoice date`

Comment: yeah, I know this option, but this means the date stays inside the invoice number as an indent, and I don't want this, I want it to stay to the right of it

Comment: you can change the view to the old way. `Pivot Table Options > Display > Classic PivotTable layout` *for XL 2007/2010*

Answer (score 1):

Select a cell in the Pivot Table, then on the Pivot Tools Design ribbon select Report Layout > Show in Tabular Form.

In Excel 2010 the Compact Form was introduced for pivot tables and all pivot tables default to Compact Form, where the row fields are indented and appear in the same column.

The screenshot shows the difference between compact form on the left and tabular form on the right.

[image]

Many people don't like the default compact form. If you would like to see this behavior changed, please place a vote in the suggestion at Excel Uservoice here: https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/10535790-allow-users-to-set-choose-defaults-via-settings

Comment: is there a way to merge tabular and compact form? for example, to use the compact form until a certain row field and then go to tabular? Thank you anyway, this already helps a lot

Comment: No, that's not an option. The setting applies to the whole pivot table.